# Harmonic analysis of sequences of Boolean functions (i.e. of words in $(\{0,1\}^n)^*$)

Tags: reference-request, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis

Is there any research on harmonic analysis of sequences of Boolean functions, which represent the application of a Boolean function on a word in $(\{0,1\}^n)^*$?

I'm looking for any reference on this, since my searches are not coming up with anything. Maybe I'm missing the right keywords.

To be more precise, consider a Boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}$, and extend it to a function $f^*:(\{0,1\}^n)^*\to \{0,1\}^*$ by $f^*(w_0w_1\cdots w_m)=f(w_0)f(w_1)\cdots f(w_m)$.

Now, for example, we can now measure the *influence* of a coordinate $i$ on $f^*$ by measuring the measure of words $x$ for which flipping the $i$-th coordinate in *some* letter of $x$, causes a change in the resulting word $f^*(x)$.

Are such notions studied anywhere?

Comment: See related question:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377771/discrete-harmonic-analysis-with-infinite-unbounded-number-of-variables/378088#378088

Comment: Yeah, it's also one of mine, and indeed related. Unfortunately, the answer there doesn't resolve things.